# margin changing drastically in bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was using div container in bootstrap and there always seems to be a margin around the container. How do I decrease the margin slightly? `mx-15 to mx-6` doesn't do anything, it still keeps the container in the center, but as soon as I do `mx-5`, then everything goes to the left and there's a huge margin on the right. how do I tackle this problem?

the versions of bootstrap and jquery that I'm used can be also seen in the bottom code block

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
 <header class="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
            <div class="container mx-5 text-center"> 
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand font-weight-bold"
                    style="font-family: Playfair Display Bold;">example</a>
                <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                    class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>

                <div id="navbarSupportedContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Home <span
                                    class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Gallery</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
```

Image of the problem
[image]

Comment: The sizing classes (padding and margin) only go to 5. There is no  mx-6 to mx-15. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve? I'm struggling to understand your problem.

Comment: how do I not bring the texts in that much center then? and still have equal margins both side. like I'm trying to get only a margin of 5 or 6 on both sides